# SQL Server 2008 Join, Union, Multiple Selects?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Really struggling with creating this view in SQL Server 2008. Multiple joins I have no problem getting my head around but am not quite sure of the best way to get the data I need this time.

I have one table, "versions", which has columns containing a JobNumber, Version number, DateCreated, CreatedBy, Status and description.

I would like all of these columns to be returned in the results.

Then it gets trickier.

I have another table called "Equipment". In that table I have 3 columns which I would like to cross reference with the "Versions" table. These columns are ModifiedVersion, ModifiedDate and ModifiedBy. What I need to do is find the last date a row was modified and return that in the same row as the version number from the previous table.

So the final results would be:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Job Number</td>
    <td>Version</td>
    <td>Date Created</td>
    <td>Created By</td>
    <td>Last Modified</td>
    <td>Last Modified By</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
    <td>01-01-2016</td>
    <td>User 12</td>
    <td>31-01-2016</td>
    <td>User 16</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>2.00</td>
    <td>21-03-2016</td>
    <td>User 8</td>
    <td>15-06-2016</td>
    <td>User 11</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
    <td>01-01-2016</td>
    <td>User 12</td>
    <td>31-01-2016</td>
    <td>User 16</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>2.00</td>
    <td>21-03-2016</td>
    <td>User 8</td>
    <td>15-06-2016</td>
    <td>User 11</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>3.00</td>
    <td>01-04-2016</td>
    <td>User 8</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

So the problem is how do I select the last modified date (easy enough using "MAX" I know) but cross reference that with the version number from the versions table.

Both the versions and equipment tables also have a "JobNumber" column which needs to have a join between them.

Finally I will then do a join on the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy columns to giv ethe actual name of the user held in a users table.

I've played around with using derived tables and various joins, I can get pretty close but get problems when different users have made modifications and if no modifications have been made. If no modifications have been made I would like the NULL values to be in the results. It's the grouping of the ModifiedBy column where it seems to go wrong.

The closest I can get is like this:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.ID, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.JobNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.VersionNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.DateCreated, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.CreatedBy,     
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedVersion, 
    MAX(dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedDate) AS LastModifiedDate, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedBy
FROM         
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment ON dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.VersionNumber = dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedVersion
GROUP BY 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.ID, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.JobNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.VersionNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.DateCreated, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.CreatedBy, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedVersion, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedBy
```

This is close but I get 3 results rows instead of the 2 I would like to get. This seems to be because the modifiedBy column has different user ID's. If I remove the "ModifiedBy" from the select completely I get the results I am after.

Any advice, tips, help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: if there more than one `ModifiedBy`, which one do you want to see?

Comment: I would only want the one that corresponds with the most recent modified date.

Comment: then use _Serg_ answer with `OUTER APPLY` just change ordering to your needs for ex. `order by date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT     
    pev.ID, 
    pev.JobNumber, 
    pev.VersionNumber, 
    pev.DateCreated, 
    pev.CreatedBy,     
    pe.LastModifiedDate,
    pe.ModifiedBy
FROM         
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions  pev
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) pe.ModifiedDate AS LastModifiedDate
        ,pe.ModifiedBy 
    FROM dbo.t_ProjectEquipment pe
    WHERE pe.ModifiedVersion = pev.VersionNumber 
    ORDER BY ModifiedBy DESC
) pe
```

Comment: Only thing was I had to change the date order to ASC to get the most recent change, guessing that is because of the TOP 1. Only other thing I now need to do is Join my Users table to the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy columns to return the usernames. Where abouts would those joins go?

Comment: Add 2 LEFT JOINs at the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT     
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.ID, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.JobNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.VersionNumber, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.DateCreated, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.CreatedBy,     
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedVersion, 
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedDate,
    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedBy
FROM   dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT  E1.ModifiedVersion, E2.ModifiedDate, E1.ModifiedBy
                FROM     t_ProjectEquipment E1
                INNER JOIN 
                    (SELECT ModifiedVersion, MAX(ModifiedDate) AS ModifiedDate
                    FROM    dbo.t_ProjectEquipment 
                    GROUP BY ModifiedVersion, ModifiedBy
                    ) E2
                ON E1.ModifiedVersion = E2.ModifiedVersion
                )   t_ProjectEquipment

    ON dbo.t_ProjectEquipmentVersions.VersionNumber = t_ProjectEquipment.ModifiedVersion
```

Use JobId in joins where required.